# How would you say "Phone Banking" (like in a Call Center) in Spanish

Tags: traducción

I'm translating a form in which people can select items they'd like to volunteer for. For example: "Organize and Event."

One of the items is "Phone Banking" which refers to making phone calls, potentially in a call center. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_bank): "A political campaign strategy to collect voter data and get out the vote."

Without your input I might just use "Call Center":

> Centro de Atención

But I'm not actually sure if "Phone Banking" occurs in a call center.

I bet there are other options, and look forward to your input.

Comment: When you say Phone Banking do you mean operating your bank account over the telephone? This would be its usual meaning in the dialect spoken in south east England.

Comment: You can say "banca telefónica". If you want to use "centro de atención", you could say "centro de atención telefónica".

Comment: @mdewey I do not mean doing banking over the telephone. In this case "phone banking" refers to "A political campaign strategy to collect voter data and get out the vote".

Comment: @Gustavson would "banca telefónica" indicate the activity of political campaigning as opposed to referring to making financial transactions with a bank over the phone?

Comment: Note that phone banking doesn't exclusively refer to political operations.  You can phone bank to request donations, or similar things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option that fits your example would be ***captación telefónica***, or ***captación por teléfono***.

The term *captación* is the one commonly used in Spanish to talk about targeting and recruitment of people for your cause: *campaña de captación*, *estrategias de captación*, etc.

> [**captación**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7M5AvyH)
>   1. f. Acción y efecto de [**captar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7M88XDA).
>
> > 4. tr. Atraer a alguien o ganar su voluntad o afecto.
> >     5. tr. Atraer, conseguir o lograr benevolencia, estimación, atención, antipatía, etc., de alguien. U. t. c. prnl.

And *telefónica / por teléfono* just means "by phone".